# Ace oledb connection close file still in use error

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-2016, oledbconnection, aceoledb

Recently I face an issue on Excel 2016. After i close the connection string on excel 2016 environment the system still lock the excel from editing (say that file in use). but the code is working perfectly on excel 2007 and 2010 environment (after connection close, the file is ready for my next function to open and edit).

on excel 2016 environment it seem like the file need to locked for 75 second after that it automatically unlocked, but this won't happen on excel 2007 and 2010 environment

where should i change it?

```
Public Function gf_ExcelConnection(ByRef strLocation As String, ByRef sWorksheetName As String, _
                                   ByRef lExcelDataset As DataSet, ByRef iLastRow As Integer, _
                                   ByRef sColumn As String) As Boolean

    Dim strExcelConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strLocation & _
                                 "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""

    Dim ExcelConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strExcelConn)
    Dim ExcelCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
    Dim ExcelDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

    Try
        gf_ExcelConnection = True

        ExcelCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sWorksheetName + "A1:" & sColumn & iLastRow & "] "
        ExcelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = ExcelCommand
        ExcelDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = ExcelConn

        MsgBox(103)

        ExcelConn.Open()
        ExcelDataAdapter.Fill(lExcelDataset, "ImportTable")
        ExcelConn.Close()
        ExcelConn.Dispose()

        MsgBox(104)

    Catch ex As Exception
        gf_ExcelConnection = False
        gclsError.gf_ErrorHandler("InvalidIncorrectFile", Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error, False)
        ExcelConn.Close()
    Finally
        ExcelConn.Close()
        ExcelConn.Dispose()
        ExcelConn = Nothing

        MsgBox(105)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Please remove all the `Close` and `Dispose` calls and put [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) around all involved objects (`ExcelConn`, `ExcelCommand`, `ExcelDataAdapter`).

Comment: in this example how i put using?

Answer (score 2):

Problem detected and solve

This problem due to the recent Microsoft update on MS office product.

After i uninstall and reinstall the AccessDatabaseEngine (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable). hooray .. the error didn't appear

Comment: It's great & Nice & Thanks Leezone Lee !